# Best practice interface for custom hooks with function arguments

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a custom hook to detect clicks inside/outside a given `HTMLElement`.

Since the hook accepts a function as an argument, it seems like either the input needs to be wrapped in a `useCallback` or stored inside the hook with `useRef` to prevent `useEffect` from triggering repeatedly.

Are both of the following approaches functionally the same?

**Approach One (preferred)**

```
// CALLER
useClickInsideOutside({
  htmlElement: htmlRef.current,
  onClickOutside: () => {
    // Do something via anonymous function
  },
});

// HOOK
const useClickInsideOutside = ({
  htmlElement,
  onClickOutside,
}) => {
  const onClickOutsideRef = useRef(onClickOutside);

  onClickOutsideRef.current = onClickOutside;

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClick(event) {
      if (htmlElement && !htmlElement.contains(event.target)) {
          onClickOutsideRef.current && onClickOutsideRef.current();
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener(MOUSE_DOWN, handleClick);
    return () => { document.removeEventListener(MOUSE_DOWN, handleClick); };
  }, [htmlElement]);
}
```

**Approach Two**

```
// CALLER
const onClickOutside = useCallback(() => {
  // Do something via memoized callback
}, []);

useClickInsideOutside({
  htmlElement: htmlRef.current,
  onClickOutside,
});

// HOOK
const useClickInsideOutside = ({
  htmlElement,
  onClickOutside,
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClick(event) {
      if (htmlElement && !htmlElement.contains(event.target)) {
        onClickOutside();
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener(MOUSE_DOWN, handleClick);
    return () => { document.removeEventListener(MOUSE_DOWN, handleClick); };
  }, [htmlElement, onClickOutside]);
}
```

Does the first one (which I prefer, because it seems to make the hook easier to use/rely on fewer assumptions) work as I imagine? Or might `useEffect` suffer from enclosing stale function references inside `handleClick`?

Comment: AFAIK the second approach is fine. `useEffect` doesn't memoize anything.

Comment: @Sheraff in the **Approach One** do you think `onClickOutsideRef.current` will always refer to an up-to-date function? Or might that get state if it changes after `useEffect` fires?

Comment: It will always be "up to date".

Answer (score 0):

`useCallback` is the right approach for this. However, I think I'd design it in a way where I could abstract the memo-ing away from the consumer:

```js
/**
 * @param {MutableRefObject<HTMLElement>} ref
 * @param {Function} onClickOutside
 */
const useClickInsideOutside = (ref, onClickOutside) => {
  const { current: htmlElement } = ref;

  const onClick = useCallback((e) => {
    if (htmlElement && !htmlElement.contains(e.target)) {
      onClickOutside();
    }
  }, [htmlElement, onClickOutside])

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener(MOUSE_DOWN, onClick);
    return () => document.removeEventListener(MOUSE_DOWN, onClick);;
  }, [onClick]);
}
```

And since I already touched on design, I'd try to make the design resemble similar API functions where 2 arguments are [in]directly related. I'd end up looking like this:

```js
// Consumer component
const ref = useRef()

useClickOutside(ref, () => {
   // do stuff in here
})
```

Comment: Won't every render in the calling component still cause useCallback to be invalidated? This seems to require that `onClickOutside` remain stable, since it's in a dependency array. Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually that's a very good point. I need to read the docs some more

Comment: Hooks are an absolute brain buster. Been using them for 1+ years and still question some of my assumptions about them on a daily basis!